# How to cherry-pick a commit and only apply to certain files?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

Let say I have two git branches:

1. branch `a` with files 1 and 2
2. branch `b` with file 2

I have a commit in branch `a` which modified file 1 and 2.
I checkout branch `b` trying to cherrypick this commit but I only want the part of the commit that changes file 2 (because branch b does not have file 1).

How is this possible?

Comment: Branches don't "have" files. Branches, to the extent that they are even a thing, have commits. Every commit has _all_ the files. You may have _changed_ just a certain file at the time you made a certain commit, but the commit has _all the files_. It is a snapshot of the _entire_ state of things at the time it is created.

Comment: @matt - OR, the commits on one branch have a file, and the commits on another don't (becuase the file wasn't created in that other branch's history, or was deleted).  A commit does not automatically "have all the files".  (And to be clear - Yes, in git terms, saying "commit on a branch" is tenuous, and "file on a branch" moreso, but OP's meaning is perfectly clear nonetheless.)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use cherry-pick normally.  The attempt to apply a change to a non-existing file should conflict (so it won't automatically commit), and then you can use

```
git rm path/to/file1
```

and then commit.

More generally, you could use `git cherr-pick -n` to ensure that no commit is made even in cases where the patch doesn't conflict, then make whatever edits you want before committing.